# AngularJS - Inject a service into index.html

Tags: angularjs

I have some configuration values that vary from environment to environment. I need access to them in the index.html file because it pertains to Google Analytics. I have an Angular service to provides access to them, however it seems that I can't inject anything into index.html.

In my index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
...
...
...
<script>
    (function(dataservice){
            dataservice.doSomething();
    })();
</script>
```

"dataservice", the injected service, is undefined.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you mean that you can't inject anything into index.html? Updating your post with the failing code will let us see what the issue might be.

Comment: See edits above please.

Comment: Angular won't inject services into any random piece of javascript. You need to place that function into a controller or directive or another service to take care of injection.

Comment: A controller within index.html? Seems like maybe I should try to put this in a config block, maybe? I'm new to Angular, so excuse these questions.

Comment: If you're getting the values from a service you can't access a service in config, but you could use a run block instead, which runs after all of your services are instantiated. Run blocks are meant to "kickstart" the app, so it sounds like they would be appropriate if you only need to get the values once.

Answer (score 2):

Define a controller and then use dependency injection to invoke your service:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, dataservice) {
    dataservice.doSomething();
});
```

Best of luck.